# jQuery Deferred's, $.when() and the fail() callback arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm getting an unexpected result when using `$.when()` when one of the deferred operations does not succeed.

Take this JavaScript, which created 2 deferreds. The first one succeeds and the second one fails.

```
var f1 = function() {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        dfd.resolve('123 from f1');
    }).promise();
};

var f2 = function() {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        dfd.reject('456 from f2');
    }).promise();
};

$.when(f1(), f2())
    .then(function(f1Val, f2Val) {
        alert('success! f1, f2: ' + JSON.stringify([f1Val, f2Val]));
    })
    .fail(function(f1Val, f2Val) {
        alert('fail!    f1, f2: ' + JSON.stringify([f1Val, f2Val]));
    });
```

Run it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/r2d3j/2/

I get `fail!    f1, f2: ["456 from f2", null]`

The problem is that in the `.fail()` callback the value passed with the `f2()` rejection, is being routed to the first argument, where i expect the `f1Value`.  Which means that I don't really have a way of know which deferred object actually posted that `reject()`, and I also dont know which operation that failure data actually belongs to.

I would have expected that `.fail()` would get arguments `null, '456 from f2'` since the first deferred did not fail.  Or am I just not doing deferreds right way here?

How do I know which deferreds failed, and which rejection arguments belong to which failed deferred if the argument order in the callback is not respected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, the "reject" and "fail" paths are handled by two totally separate queues, so it just doesn't work the way you expect.

In order to know which original Deferred failed from the "when()" group, you could have them pass themselves along with the ".reject()" call as part of an object literal or something.

Comment: Hmm, not quite how I would have designed it, but I guess that makes my result make sense.

Comment: @Mootoo jQuery has changed a lot since this question was answered. It now uses standard Promise semantics.

Answer (score 27):

`$.when()` will execute the failed callback (2nd parameter passed to `then()`) immediately if any one of the parameters fails. It's by design. To quote the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

> In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred. Note that some of the Deferreds may still be unresolved at that point. If you need to perform additional processing for this case, such as canceling any unfinished ajax requests, you can keep references to the underlying jqXHR objects in a closure and inspect/cancel them in the failCallback.

There's actually no built-in way of getting a callback that waits untils all of them are finished regardless of their success/failure status.

So, I built a `$.whenAll()` for you :) 
It always waits until all of them resolve, one way or the other:

http://jsfiddle.net/InfinitiesLoop/yQsYK/51/

```
$.whenAll(a, b, c)
    .then( callbackUponAllResolvedOrRejected );
```

Comment: You say "will execute the then() callback immediately", but the quote you include says "immediately fires the failCallbacks" - so which is it? `\-:`

Comment: @hippietrail It's both. then() fires when deferred is "resolved" OR "rejected". This classifies as a rejection, so it fires.

Comment: no, it doesn't fire the then callback .. it fires the fail callback. (which technically can be the 'second' callback passed to 'then', but in any case it's not the same as the 'then' callback which most people reading your answer will assume is the 'success' callback).

Comment: This answer was still helpful, nearly 5 years later! thanks!

Comment: @InfinitiesLoop Do we have any updates here? Or still considered to be the best answer provided as a solution?

Comment: you can use `Promise.allSettled`, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this same problem, and I dealt with it by using the .always callback and inspecting my array of deferred objects. I had an unknown number of ajax calls, so I had to do the following:

```
// array of ajax deletes
var deletes = [];
$checkboxes.each(function () {
    deletes.push(deleteFile(this));
});

$.when.apply($, deletes)
  .always(function () {
      // unfortunately .fail shortcircuits and returns the first fail,
      // so we have to loop the deferred objects and see what happened.

      $.each(deletes, function () {
          this.done(function () {
              console.log("done");
          }).fail(function () {
              console.log("fail");
          });
      });
  });
```

The deleteFile method returns a promise, which has .done or .fail callbacks.

This allows you to take action after all deferreds have completed. In my case I'm going to show a delete file error summary.

I just tried this, and unfortunately I had to put a interval timer to check that they were all truly done after my $.each on the deferred objects. This seems odd and counterintuitive.

Still trying to understand these deferreds!

Comment: always will also "short-circuit" if any of the deferreds fail.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but now, to wait until *all* are resolved, you can use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) since `$.ajax` deals with standard promises.

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise

Therefore you can use

```js
Promise.allSettled([$.ajax(), $.ajax()])
  .then((res) => {
    if (res[0].status === 'fulfilled') {
      console.log(res[0].value)
      // do something
    } else {
      console.error('res1 unavailable')
    }

    if (res[1].status === 'fulfilled') {
      console.log(res[1].value)
      // do something
    } else {
      console.error('res2 unavailable')
    }
  })
```

Comment: Except that IE 11 doesn't support `allSettled`.

Comment: @IanKemp interesting, I didn't know, whatever, I don't need IE, but that's a good point.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you.