# Anyway to pass the jquery deferred $.when an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when)

Is there anyway to pass the jquery deferred $.when an array of ajax functions?  Example:

```
 var arr = [
    $.getJSON(window.location, function() { alert('yes') }),
    $.getJSON(window.location, function() { alert('yes') })
 ]

 $.when(arr).then(function(a, b) {

 });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

```
$.when.apply( $, arr ).then(function( a, b ) { ... });
```

Comment: it's a duplicate question, but have an upvote anyway for writing `$.Deferred()` in the first place ;-)

Comment: I know, there isn't much out there on Deferreds!  Thanks for your help!  Thats a tricky one.