# jQuery make dynamic ajax calls and wait for them to complete

Tags: jquery

I need to make a number of ajax calls(the exact number is variable) and wait for them all to complete. My current code is as follows:

```
ajaxRequests = new Array();

ajaxRequests.push(function(){
                return jQuery.post(url: "someUrl",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data:  yourJsonData
            });



jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, ajaxRequests).done(function(){
    alert("ajax requests done");
});
```

Unfortunatly the above code is not waiting for the ajax request to finish. Any help would be apprecited.

Comment: check if the following answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865586/jquery-when-troubleshooting-with-variable-number-of-arguments

Comment: Make sure you close the parenthesis after yourJsonData. It may be causing the problem

Answer (score 4):

The answer is below: Copied from [jQuery .when troubleshooting with variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865586/jquery-when-troubleshooting-with-variable-number-of-arguments)

```
// Array of requests
var requests = Array();
requests.push($.get('responsePage.php?data=foo'));
requests.push($.get('responsePage.php?data=bar'));

var defer = $.when.apply($, requests);
defer.done(function(){

    // This is executed only after every ajax request has been completed

    $.each(arguments, function(index, responseData){
        // "responseData" will contain an array of response information for each specific request
    });

});
```

Comment: This works well when you have at least two requests to send. Otherwise you get an inconsistent behavior when it's one query or several :(