# Does $.when resolve array of deferreds in the same order as they were in the array?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, json-rpc

I have an array of an unknown number of deferreds that I'm trying to resolve with $.when. When all the deferreds have been resolved, will the '.then' function give me back the resolved deferreds in the same order as I entered then in the array?

Pseudo code example:

```
var deferreds = [];
for(0,1,2,...,x) { 
   var def = JsonRpc(...);
   deferreds.push(def);
}
$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function () {
  console.log(arguments.length); //outputs a number >= 0
  for(0,1,2,...,x) {
     console.log("Defered: ", arguments[0,1,2,...,x])
  }
});
```

Will deferreds[0] be equal to arguments[0] and deferreds[x] be equal to arguments[x]?

Thanks in advance for any and all replies!
//Edvin

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239821/jquery-when-multiple-ajax-requests-order-of-responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation :

> The arguments passed to the doneCallbacks provide the resolved values
>   for each of the Deferreds, and matches the order the Deferreds were
>   passed to jQuery.when(). For example:

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();

$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // "Fish"
    console.log( v2 ); // "Pizza"
});

d1.resolve( "Fish" );
d2.resolve( "Pizza" );
```

A little example :

```js
var deferreds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var def = $.Deferred();
  deferreds.push(def);
}

$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
  console.log(arguments.length); //outputs a number >= 0
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log("Defered: ", arguments[i]);
  }
});

deferreds[1].resolve("Fish2");
deferreds[2].resolve("Fish3");
deferreds[0].resolve("Fish1");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Very good example. I had already read that part of the documentation but I didn't know if it applied to arrays as well. I'm still quite new to Javascript so had to make sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking each question/statement one at a time ...

> Does $.when resolve array of deferreds in the same order as they were in the array?

No. `$.when()` does not resolve the deferreds/promises passed to it. It *aggregates* deferreds/promises, each of which settles (resolves or rejects) by some other means. Here, "aggregate" means to accept a set of promises and return a single promise.

> I have an array of an unknown number of deferreds that I'm trying to resolve with $.when.

Same again, `$.when()` doesn't resolve the deferreds/promises passed to it.

> When all the deferreds have been resolved, will the '.then' function give me back the resolved deferreds in the same order as I entered then in the array?

No, `.then()` doesn't give back deferreds, resolved or otherwise. But yes, the arguments of its success callback function (if it fires) will be congruous with the original array.

> Will deferreds[0] be equal to arguments[0] and deferreds[x] be equal to arguments[x]?

No, they won't be *equal*, but they will *correspond*, index-by-index. Each argument will be the *result* delivered by the corresponding deferred/promise in the original array.