# What is cleanest way to turn Array of JQuery Promises into a JQuery Promise of an Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, promise

I run into the situation where I have multiple JQuery Promises in an Array

```
var arrayOfPromises = [ $.Deferred(), $.Deferred(), $.Deferred(), $.Deferred() ]
```

and need to turn it into a JQuery Promise of an Array

```
var promiseOfArray = someTransform(arrayOfPromises)
```

where

```
promiseOfArray.done(function(anArray){
  alert(anArray.join(","));
});
```

creates an alert with text

> result1,result2,result3,result4

I currently define `someTransform` in coffeescript as

```
someTransform = (arrayOfPromises) ->
  $.when(arrayOfPromises...).pipe (promises...) ->
    promises
```

which transforms to the following javascript

```
var someTransform,
  __slice = [].slice;

someTransform = function(arrayOfPromises) {
  return $.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises).pipe(function() {
    var promises;
    promises = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
    return promises;
  });
};
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qk2mT/3/) of the result I'm looking for.

I was wondering if there is a better(shorter,cleaner) way to define `someTransform` to achieve the same result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1048572)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can just [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the array as the arguments to `$.when`.

```
var promiseOfArray = $.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises);
```

To make the usage of this clearer, I like adding a method to `$`:

```
$.whenall = function(arr) { return $.when.apply($, arr); };
```

Now you can do:

```
$.whenall([deferred1, deferred2, ...]).done(...);
```

---

**Update:** By default, the `done` handler gets each result passed as a separate argument; you don't get an array of results.

Since you need to handle an arbitrary number of Deferreds, you can use the special implicit [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object to loop over the results.

```
$.whenall([d1, d2, ...]).done(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        // do something with arguments[i]
    }
});
```

If you really just want to join the string result of all your Deferreds, we can employ a little array hackery.  `arguments` is array-like, but is not an `Array`:

```
$.whenall([d1, d2, ...]).done(function() {
    alert(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ','));
});
```

---

If you want to return an array of results to your `done` callback, we can tweak `whenall` [to do it](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/9YEsP/):

```
$.whenall = function(arr) {
    return $.when.apply($, arr).pipe(function() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    });
};
```

Comment: I think the OP is actually asking for a "shorter, cleaner" way and is already aware of `.apply()`

Comment: I'll make the question clearer but I believe that this will call done with `result1,result2,...` but I'm looking to have it call done with single param of `[result1,result2,...]`

see http://jsfiddle.net/qk2mT/2/ "throws Object 0 has no method 'join' "

Comment: @Soldier.moth: The `done` handler does not get an array of results; rather, it gets passed *n* arguments, where *n* is the number of Deferreds you passed in originally.  Use the implicit `arguments` object to loop through the results.

Comment: @josh3736: Yeah, I was hoping nice method to do the transformation of `arguments` to an array for me. Might be accomplished by defined `$.whenall` like `function(arr) {
    return $.when.apply($,arr).pipe(function(){
       return [].slice.call(arguments,0);
    });
}`

Comment: @Soldier.moth: Yep, that would do it.  I'd use `Array.prototype.slice` instead of `[]` so you aren't unnecessarily creating an Array instance.  See update.

Answer (score 6):

It also bothered me alot to always type the "ugly" line `$.when.apply` when we need to invoke it on multiple promises. But `Function.prototype.bind` for the rescue!

```
var when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( jQuery.when, null );
```

Now, we can just call

```
when( someArrayWithPromises ).done(function() {
});
```

<sup>`Function.prototype.bind` is part of ES5 and is very widely available across browsers. There are a ton of easy *shims* available if you need to support very old'ish browsers aswell</sup>

Comment: You have to be careful with `bind` since it isn't available in [older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility).