# how to know when several callbacks have been successfully executed with no returned promises

Tags: javascript

**!!! this question is not about how to pass an array of promises to the `when` function since neither `file` method nor `onload` return promises, its not a duplicate**

I have a custom method that executes async functions which DO NOT return promises. My custom method does return a promise. What is the correct way to implement the functionality - using timeout like in example 1 or checking for equality in the callback function like in example 2?
**EXAMPLE1:**

```
getAllFiles: function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var files = [];
    fileEntries.forEach(function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                files.push({
                    name: fileEntry.fullPath,
                    content: e.target.result
                });
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    });

    //this resolves the deffered    
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
       if (files.length === fileEntries.length) {
           def.resolve(files);
           clearInterval(interval);
       }
    }, 1000);

    return def.promise();
}
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
getAllFiles: function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var files = [];
    fileEntries.forEach(function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                files.push({
                    name: fileEntry.fullPath,
                    content: e.target.result
                });
                //this resolves the deffered
                if (files.length === fileEntries.length) {
                   def.resolve(files);
                   clearInterval(interval);
                }
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    });

    return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery, which means you'd be able to take advantage of [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6538470/218196

Comment: @zzzzBov, I don't see how I can use jQuery's when here. Could you guys please provide an example specific to my situation? To user `when` async methods should return promises, but neither `file` method nor `onload` return promises.

Comment: Your second example is incorrect because you resolve the deferred more than once (on every loop iteration, in fact). Depending on your requirements, a timer may not be reliable enough. Have you tried maintaining a counter, and only resolving the deferred when the last file has been read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply *make* a promise for each async function (`onload` handler) then!

```
getAllFiles: function () {
    var deferreds = fileEntries.map(function(fileEntry){
        var def = $.Deferred();
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                def.resolve({
                    name: fileEntry.fullPath,
                    content: e.target.result
                });
            };
            reader.onerror = def.reject; // don't forget error handling!
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }, def.reject); // here as well
        return def;
    });
    return $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
        var files = $.map(arguments, function(args) { return args[0]; });
        return files;
    });
}
```

<sub>(the `map`ping over the arguments in the `then` is necessary because [jQuery's `$.when` result is so ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376219/1048572))</sub>

To answer your actual question:

> What is the correct way to implement the functionality - using timeout like in example 1 or checking for equality in the callback function like in example 2?

Do it from the callback. Polling results with `setInterval` is despised (it's slower, won't catch errors and even leak in the error case).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond, it gave me new insight into Jquery's defferds :). One question though, why do you return `def` from `file` callback instead of `def.promise()`?

Comment: You can do either. A `Deferred` implements the `Promise` interface that `when` uses, calling `.promise()` on it would just construct another object.

Comment: Thanks. But then the `def` can be resolved outside for the `getAllFiles` function, right? If we return `Promise` we prevent it. I also don't see why I need this `var files = $.map(arguments, function(args) { return args[0]; });` since arguments already contains an array of objects.? I can simple turn it into real Array by `return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

Comment: What is weird though is that when I call the method like that `getAllFiles().done(function (files) { });` the `files` variable contains only the first object instead of array returned by `then`. Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: No, `def` cannot be resolved outside `getAllFiles` because we don't return the `def`, but the promise constructed through `$.when`. That's why it's save to use a deferred here. If you'd put reading a single file entry in a separate function, then there you should indeed use `.promise()`. It might be cleaner here as well, if not only for reducing confusion :-)

Comment: The problem is that `arguments` in the `when` callback is not an array-like object of the objects, but an array-like object of argument arrays that contain the objects. Check out the link in the small note below the code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that explains the behavior. Event if I put `return $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {return 1})` I still get the first object passed to `def.resolve()` when I call `getAllFiles().done(function (files) { })` - I expect `files` to be `1` here, but it's not

Comment: _but an array-like object of argument arrays that contain the objects_ - it doesn't seem to be so - `arguments[1][0]` is undefined.

Comment: Uh, are you using one of the very very old jQuery version where `then` was non-standard and you have to use `pipe` instead?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it seems that I am. I'm new to the project and for some reason expected jQuery to be the newest one. I'll use `pipe` then. Thanks again! Best!