# How do I get resolved data from multiple promises at once with jquery .when().apply()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am new to javascript. I have an array of promises that are for asynchronous Ajax calls using $.getJSON. The number of promises can vary. So to resolve them, I am using

```js
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(data) {
```

I am doing .apply because I don't know how many promises there are, so I give it an array of promises instead. The problem I am having is the data variable only returns data for the first promise. If I had two promises, I could do this

```js
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(firstData, secondData) {
```

But because the number of promises is unknown, I cannot setup the right arguments for the callback function in `.done()`. I want to get an array containing the resolved data for each Ajax call in the `.done()` callback if that is possible

Comment: [`$.when` is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376219/1048572). Don't use it any more, just go for `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can come in handy.

Try something like this

```js
$.when(...promises).done((...results) => {
  // results is an array
})
```

This works by

1. Treating the `promises` array like individual function arguments

   ```js
   $.when(promises[0], promises[1], ..., promises[promises.length - 1])
   ```
2. Combining the individual arguments for the `.done()` callback function into an array

---

For completeness, this is really one of those situations where [you might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). Modern browsers support [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as very good vanilla JS replacements for `$.when` and `$.ajax`

```js
const getJson = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`)
  return res.json()
}

Promise.all([ getJson(url1), getJson(url2) ]).then(results => {
  // results is an array
})
```

---

If you're one of those poor, unfortunate souls who still have to support Internet <strike>Exploder</strike> Explorer, you can use `apply()` and the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```js
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
  var results = arguments
})
```

Comment: if you are in an environment without spread syntax (in other words, Internet Explorer) then you'd use the *array-like* `arguments` in the function to access all the arguments

Comment: @Bravo true. Would need to stick with `apply` for the `.when()` part. I'll add that in

Comment: it is working in all the ways now. I will stick to arguments object because I do have to support ie ): Thank you for your help

Comment: @JoeChris _"I do have to support ie"_... I'm so sorry. Take heart that IE 11 only has one more year of official support left (till June 2022)