# Is it okay to use synchronous AJAX for this purpose?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Basically, I'm looping through a query of FOOD in my webpage. 
Now each food in a different table, FLAVOR (linked by a unique FOOD ID), have a flavor. 
Now, while I loop through the FOOD, is it okay to grab the flavor with a synchronous AJAX call or am I being stupid and should do something else?

The reason I ask is since from what I understand synchronous AJAX calls should be avoided as they aren't exactly the optimal way to do things. I just can't think of a good way to do it, as I can't do it as a callback function for the reason that it'd break out of the FOOD loop that goes through the FOOD query.

Comment: why are you doing any of that on the client side?

Comment: well, I simplified things for the question. The code is being called from a gmap application and as far as I know, the only way to do it is client side.

Comment: This sounds like it would be very bad performance wise, even if you use AJAX calls. If your only option is to use an ajax call per food, don't display the flavor unless the user asks for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous AJAX is never a good idea.  Since you need to wait for many actions to finish, consider using jQuery's Deferred object.

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

You can use an array of them as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627301/362536