# Waiting until AJAX completes inside an $.each loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I can't seem to get jQuery deferrers to work if they are called from an `$.each` loop.

```
var deferreds = [],
    ids = ['1234', '4321'],
    users = [];

$.each(ids, function(i,v){
    deferreds.push(
        $.getJSON('api/users/'+v, function(i,v){
            users.push(v.username);
        })
    );
});

$.when($, deferreds).done(function(){
    console.log(users);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of [`when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

In particular, the usage is missing an [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) - so it is "waiting on" $ and the deferreds array (which will "resolve" immediately), not each deferred.

Compare with:

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done..
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @matthoiland You're welcome. I've been bit by this before - it's easy to remember after that!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would link to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43066977/3109260) on a very similar thread regarding ajax calls within an each loop.

Unlike the OP's code, this method is a little more complex showing how to await the 'successes' back up through a couple of function calls and I think would be useful for many people encountering the ajax/each issue.