# Wait to complete multiple ajax calls which can run concurrently

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have three ajax calls which can run concurrently. However I want the browser to wait until all ajax calls completed. One way is to set async as false for each of them but then I lose precious time since they can run concurrently. Is there a way to run them concurrently but make the browser hangs until all completed?

Answer (score 1):

After success, call callback function:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(){ checkAjax(); }
});
```

And in callback function count how much responses you have.

```
var totalEnded = 0, totalAjax = 3;
function checkAjax() {
   totalEnded++;

   if (totalEnded == totalAjax) {
       /* Do important stuff here, or call another function */
   }
}
```

Comment: I want the browser hanged up on the ajax calls. Not just calling some javascript function when all is completed.

Comment: @araqnoon Why you want to hang browser? If it takes longer to connect, i go to watch some YouTube. Better hide or disable some elements, so no interactiosn can be made while waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then have a look at [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), you can provide a success callback which gets executed when all the requests are finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

To make work with asynchronous stuff easier, you can use the [promises pattern](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). If you're on jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). From the docs:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/p1.php" ), $.ajax( "/p2.php" )).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
     //do this when both ajax calls are done
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using deferred objects, because ajax itself returns that object. Please refer to [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when)

```
var deferreds = [
    $.post(),
    $.get(),
];
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() {
    // All ajax requests was done
});
```