# jQuery Conditional Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have 2 separate models which are populated by 2 different API calls. I do a fetch on them one-by-one and once both the model api calls are done and my view is available (then trigger deferred resolve), I have my view rendering logic i.e. write data to the view

Below is the code;

```
var myModel1 = new myModel1({
    attr1: attr1
});

var myModel2 = new myModel2({
    attr2: attr2
});

myModel1.fetch({
success: function() {
        myModel1Deferred.resolve(myModel1);
    }
});

myModel2.fetch({
success: function() {
        myModel2Deferred.resolve(myModel2);
    }
});


require(['view/my-view'], function(myView) {
    myViewDeferred.resolve(myView);
});

$.when(myModel1Deferred, myModel2Deferred, myViewDeferred).then(function(myModel1, myModel2, myView) {
    // My view rendering logic
}
```

Now the issue is that there are 2 separate cases (based on how the view is accessed):

1. In the first case, I have both the model API calls...so in this case resolve would depend on myModel1Deferred + myModel2Deferred + myViewDeferred
2. But in the 2nd case, I just need one model API call (i.e myModel1.fetch())...so in this case the resolve would depend only on
   myModel1Deferred + myViewDeferred

My question is should I have an if condition and write the `$.when().then()` separately for each condition OR can it be handled within a single `$.then().when()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can [pass an array of variable length to `$.when`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1048572) by using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). Something like

```
var promises = [
    myViewDeferred,
    myModel1Deferred
];
if (case#2)
    promises.push(myModel2Deferred);

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(view) {
    view.render.apply(view, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    // view.render(model1, [model2, …]);
});
```

Btw, instead of [using many deferreds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) your `fetch` and `require` function should simply return promises, instead of accepting callbacks.