# Combine JSON files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

All the questions I've found relating to this have been about combining JSON objects and/or strings. I am using a jQuery plugin called "Fuse", for searching the contents of the files (repo here: https://github.com/krisk/Fuse). This is the code I have so far.

```
$.getJSON("data/bn1.json", function(data) {
    start(data);
});

$.getJSON("data/bn2.json", function(data2) {
    start(data2);
});
```

Both JSON files look like this (shortened, for brevity):

```
[
 {
    "number": "001",
    "name": "Cannon",
    "rarity": "*",
    "damage": "40",
    "element": "Normal",
    "description": "A nice, big Cannon!"
 },
 {
    "number": "002",
    "name": "HiCannon",
    "rarity": "**",
    "damage": "80",
    "element": "Normal",
    "description": "A nice, big Cannon!"
 },
 {
    "number": "003",
    "name": "M-Cannon",
    "rarity": "***",
    "damage": "120",
    "element": "Normal",
    "description": "A nice, big Cannon!"
 }
]
```

The last JSON file to be called (in this case, `bn2.json`) is the one that shows up when I search. I want to search in more than two files (it'll be six files in the future). The full JS file for my project is here: https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/Gingnet/blob/master/scripts/gingnet.js (you can find my JSON files there too).

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you want to search JSON files... it appears that you want to search objects.  JSON is just a transport format.  How you combine your data, we don't know.  You didn't tell us what that data is.  I'm not sure how we can help you.

Comment: Can you get all the files as JSON strings, parse into objects, then cache locally? Your search would be against this combined local cache rather than the individual files.

Comment: @kaveman How would I do that exactly? I'm not super familiar with JSON, haha.

Comment: see Brad's answer below - essentially what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Brad, I came up with a solution:

```
var allData = [];

$.getJSON("data/bn1.json", function(data) {
    allData = allData.concat(data);
    start(allData);
});

$.getJSON("data/bn2.json", function(data2) {
    allData = allData.concat(data2);
    start(allData);
});
```

Hooray!

Comment: You're going to process your data twice?  Why not use the jQuery promise library, as suggested on my answer?

Comment: The second example you gave didn't work with my code. What I have above is a quick fix. I intend to look into promises, they sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your question boils down to, "how do I merge arrays?"  You can use [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
var allData = [];
$.getJSON("data/bn1.json", function(data) {
    allData = allData.concat(data);
});

$.getJSON("data/bn2.json", function(data2) {
    allData = allData.concat(data);
});
```

Since you're getting multiple files, it would be best to [use promises to wrap these all up](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [handle them all at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16208232/362536).  Untested, but this should get you started:

```
var urls = [
  'data/bn1.json',
  'data/bn2.json',
  'data/bn3.json'
  // etc.
];

var deferreds = [];
$.each(urls, function (index, url) {
  deferreds.push($.getJSON(url)); // Request all data simultaneously
});

$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function () { // We have all data, merge it
  var data = [];
  $.each(arguments, function (index, chunk) {
    data = data.concat(chunk);
  });
  start(data); // Do whatever you want to this new collection of data
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Brad! You helped me find a solution.