# Looping through nested deferred AJAX Calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am doing a `$.ajax(type: 'GET', data: ticket)` where `ticket` is an authentication token. `ticket` is acquired like so:

```
var newTicket = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                jsonpCallback: 'JsonPCallBack',
                data: {},
                url: "https://api.examample.com?username=bar&password=foo",
        });
```

Once I have obtained my `ticket` I can do my `GET`:

```
function getData(ticket, query) {
            return $.ajax( {
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                jsonpCallback: 'JsonPCallBack',
                data: ticket,
                url: "https://api.examample.com/?data=" + query,
            });
        }
```

Putting it together:

```
        newTicket.done(function(ticket) {

            var ticket = ticket;
            getData(ticket, query).done(function(result) {

                console.log(result);

            }); 
        });
```

This works perfectly fine - my two calls are definitely working.

My challenge is that I want to make this call again for a many values of `query`. Here is what I tried:

```
// example.com promises me that I can use ticket for multiple requests
// for one ticket I will try and do multiple requests

newTicket.done(function(ticket) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var ticket = ticket;

    // Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when
    requests = [];

    for (i in queries) {
        query = queries[i];
        requests.push(getData(ticket, query));
    }

    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function(result) {
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            console.log(calculateData(arguments[i][0]));
        }
    });

});
```

This however does NOT work. I cannot figure out why. Any advice?

I tried adding this code:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('jqXHR: ' + jqXHR);
            console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        });
```

And this gave me:

```
jqXHR: [object Object]
textStatus: parsererror
errorThrown: Error: JsonPCallBack was not called
```

**UPDATE:**
The simple case with only one request does not work if I do not specify jsonp and JsonPCallBack. It does work if I specify jsonp and JsonPCallBack.

I tried running the code with two requests in my array. Sniffing the packets I see that two requests are made with Status Code 200 OK. The response starts with `JsonPCallBack({` and contain the correct data. So when I look at the actual repsonse everything looks correct. Why do I reach `.fail()`?

Comment: Did you try adding a `fail()` handler on that `$.when.apply`? Checking whether the `done` handler gets called? You haven't shown any evidence of attempting to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: In what way it does not work?

Comment: @user1965074 It doesn't look like you did...

Comment: @user1965074 Ok, so the request is failing, apparently because the response is coming back but it's not JSONP. Have you looked at the response in your browser tools or a traffic sniffer (e.g. Fiddler) to see what the request and response look like? Is there a reason you're specifying `jsonp` and `jsonpcallback` parameters? The recommended practice is to omit them unless you specifically need them.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are using a single callback for all your requests. You should remove `jsonpCallback: 'JsonPCallBack'` and have the server use the callback parameter like clientCallBack+"("+json+")"

Answer (score 0):

The `jsonpCallback` parameter indicates the name of a function name to use for wrapping the JSONP response. jQuery automatically sets up a function with this name that waits to be called so that the data returned can be handled.

You are specifying an explicit value for this parameter, which means that *all* of the requests will be waiting on the same function name, and *all* of the responses will try to call the same function name and it will be complete chaos. There will no way to route the responses correctly.

So just don't specify that parameter or the `jsonp` parameter. The recommended practice is to not use them unless there is a specific reason to do so.

As a side note, the code to produce your array of requests can be simplified:

```
var requests = $.map(queries, function (query) {
    return getData(ticket, query);
});
```