# Group multiple AJAX success calls into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-click-event

I'm updating records in my database using a checkbox in a table. I'm trying to offer 1 Alert after ALL the updates went through, rather than alerting for each individual success call

```
  $('#update').click(function () {
$('#view_26 tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_1/records/' + id,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {field_1: 'Closed'},
    success: function (response) {
        alert('updated!');
    }
  });
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Keep a count of how many requests were made and how many "successes" you've had.  Once they are equal then do the alert.  There are several ways to implement this mechanic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count your successful calls and compare with the total number of calls.

```
 $('#update').click(function () {

var calls=$('#view_26 tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
var success=0;

$('#view_26 tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_1/records/' + id,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {field_1: 'Closed'},
    success: function (response) {
success+=1;
if(success==calls) alert('updated!');
        }

  });
```

Maybe you should also catch unsuccessful calls.

Answer (score 0):

Can you build and PUT the entire JSON array instead of one row at a time?  This, of course, would require modifying your web service to get the record id from the JSON instead of the url.  It's a better practice to limit your calls in this manner.

```
$('#update').click(function () {

var myJSON=[];
$('#view_26 tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  myJSON.push({ID:id,field_1:'Closed'});
});
//end of each


$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_1/records/',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: myJSON,
    success: function (response) {
        alert('updated!');
    }

  });
```

Comment: I would have taken this route however the service doesn't allow for batch updating like that -- they need to be individual calls. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to compare the length of checkboxes against the index to see if they are equal, like below.

```
$('#update').click(function () {
    var checkboxes = $('#view_26 tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked'),
        len = checkboxes.length;

    checkboxes.each(function(i) {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_1/records/' + id,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: {field_1: 'Closed'},
            success: function (response) {
                if (i === len - 1 ) {
                    alert('updated!');
                }
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$('#update').click(function () {
  var elem = $('#view_26 tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  var res = $.map(elem, function(el, i) {
    var id = $(el).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_1/records/' + id,
      type: 'PUT',
      data: {field_1: 'Closed'}
    });
  });
  $.when.apply($, res)
  .then(function() {
      alert("updated!");
  }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus +" "+ jqxhr.status +" "+ errorThrown);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="update">update</button>
<table id="view_26">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="0">
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr id="1">
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr id="2">
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: This one's a bit more advanced than I can tackle right now but will definitely study it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Similar to `js` at OP, utilizing `$.map()` instead of `.each()`; `res` returns an array of `deferred` objects from `$.map()` , with `success`, `error` callbacks passed to `.then()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when . You are welcome:)