# jQuery wait for .then() callback function is completed by promise object

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, promise, deferred

I have the code in native JavaScript (I simplified it):

```
var finalArray = [];

for (var i; i < 3; i++) {
    var a = -1;  // set the default value
    var b = Math.random();

    ymaps.route(someArray[i]).then(function (res) {
        a = res.getCoordinates();     
    });

    finalArray.push([a, b]);
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

There is some third-party framework called `ymaps` which has a method `route` which returns a *promise* object. Problem cases in that I need to wait until *promise.then* callback function is done, then continue the main code with function `finalArray.push([a, b]);`, or, rather, synchronize asyncronous processes.

Result of code I wrote above is

```
[
    [-1, /*random*/],
    [-1, /*random*/],
    [-1, /*random*/]
]
```

But instead of `-1` - the default `var a` value, some plural number (changed `var a` in *promise.then* callback function) must be there.

Comment: Please add the code for the callback function you pass to `.then()`. There is no way to answer your question without seeing it.

Comment: Look up better, here it is
`function(res){ a = res.getCoordinates(); }`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just "continue with the main code". Promises are asynchronous, and your callback (that assigns `a`) will be executed only after you have tried to use `a` in `finalArray.push([a, b]);`. See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572).

Instead, you will need to put your main code in a callback as well. You can get another promise for the results of all three loop-generated promises, see [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1048572).

```
function makePromise(a, b) {
    // scope necessary for closure
    return ymaps.route(someArray[i]).then(function(res) {
        a = res.getCoordinates();
        return [a, b];
    });
}

var promises = [];
for (var i; i < 3; i++)
    promises.push(makePromise(-1, Math.random()));
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    var finalArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    console.log(finalArray);
});
```