# Jquery Promise with Recursive Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, typescript, jquery-deferred

I have read other answers here and couldn't exactly match my issue. Should be simple for someone with lots of experience in Promises. Code below, I need help fixing up the Recursive function because everything that happens in that ajax call is not available in first done. Code below will explain (Note the TypeScript syntax):

```
//Main
private Start(){
    this.PopulateSomething().done(() => {
        alert('done');
    });
}

private PopulateSomething(): JQueryPromise<any> {
    var dfd: JQueryDeferred<any> = jQuery.Deferred<any>();

        //app.ExecuteAjax is just a wrapper for a ajax call.. note i'm using callbacks
        app.ExecuteAjax("SomeParamater1", function (returnedObject) {
            //Do something with returnedObject                    
            $.each(returnedObject.something, function () {
                app.RecursivelyDoSomething(this);                                                        
            });                              
            dfd.resolve();
        });
    return dfd.promise();
}

private RecursivelyDoSomething(Thing: any) {     
    //Do something with Thing           

    //Anything that happens within this Ajax call is not available when alert('done'); is executed
    app.ExecuteAjax("SomeParamater1", function (returnedObject) {
        $.each(returnedObject.something, function () {
            app.RecursivelyDoSomething(this);                                                        
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You will need to make `RecursivelyDoSomething` return a promise. Instead of `$.each` use `$.map` so that you get an array of promises, which you then can [wait for](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1048572). Oh, and don't use the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I like the idea and approach. Still struggling to visualise it though. I understand returning a promise on RecursivelyDoSomething function but when do I actually call the resolve? Sorry, I know only 2 things about promises: promise, and resolve :-)

Comment: A promise that is returned from a function is resolved with that function's eventual result, when everything that the function does is done. So it would resolve when the ajax call and all recursive calls are done.

Comment: Q1: Are you  populating a tree or something using the result of each Ajax call to provide more nodes? Q2: Do you want the operations to run sequentially, in parallel (restricted by the browser throttling), or some combination of the two? Q3: Is the data fixed-depth, or does this really need to be recursive?

Comment: Hey @TrueBlueAussie. Thanks for your interest in helpgin solve this. Q1: Yes, I am populating a tree (Using Knockout recursive Template). Q2. I can do syncronous but don't want the browser to lock up. Q3. Unfortunately, it's not fixed depth data, so has to be true recursion...

Answer (score -1):

Seems you want to `recursively` make `ajax` queries and only want to execute `done` after the last one. One way to do that would be to keep a count of pending ajax queries, increment this count based on `Thing` and decrement this count from based on `Ajax` finishing. And then only resolve `dfd` once count = 0.

Comment: No, please not. Use promises when you have them at hand! No need for manually counting anything.