# Unable to access nested Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a Javascript object, that contains nested objects, but I can't seem to access the nested objects - the objects are formatted like:

```
Object
  0: Object
    colour: Object
      colour: value
      element: value
    kelvin: Object
      colour: value
      element: value
    status: Object
      state: value
      element: value
  1: Object
    colour: Object
      colour: value
      element: value
    kelvin: Object
    status: Object
```

When I stringify the parent object, it doesn't include the nested objects:

```
{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{}}
```

Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code where I'm having issues:

```
function updateStatus()
{
    var triggers = {};

    counter = 0;

    $.when(
        $("form[type='light_status']").each(function(f){
            var options = {};
            form = $(this);
            selector = form.attr('selector');
            id = form.attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/status/' + selector + '/' + id,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    var data = $(data)[0];
                    var switchInput = '#'+data.selector+'-'+data.id;
                    if(data.status == 'on')
                    {
                        options.status = {element: switchInput, state: true};
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.status = {element: switchInput, state: false};
                    }
                    options.colour = {element: '#'+data.id+'-colourpicker', colour: data.colour};
                    options.kelvin = {element: '#'+data.id+'-kelvinpicker', colour: data.colour};
                }
            });
            triggers[counter] = options;
            counter++;
        })
    ).done( function() {
        console.log(triggers); //can see all nested objects
        console.log(triggers[0].colour); //returns null
        console.log('triggers:' + JSON.stringify(triggers)); // can only see parent object
    });

}
```

Comment: you are using when, but each method doesn't return any defer, so done will gets called immediately, it will not wait to complete ajax request.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange Well thats awkward! Obviously I'm a JS novice - any suggestions on how I can restructure this code to work as expected would be appreciated. The number of ajax calls won't be a known number, hence the $.each() loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect all defer in an array and then you can pass it to `$.when()`.

> **Here is your answer**

```js
function updateStatus() {
    var triggers = {};

    counter = 0, deferArr = [];


    $("form[type='light_status']").each(function(f) {
      var options = {};
      form = $(this);
      selector = form.attr('selector');
      id = form.attr('id');
      var _d = $.ajax({
        url: '/status/' + selector + '/' + id,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          var data = $(data)[0];
          var switchInput = '#' + data.selector + '-' + data.id;
          if (data.status == 'on') {
            options.status = {
              element: switchInput,
              state: true
            };
          } else {
            options.status = {
              element: switchInput,
              state: false
            };
          }
          options.colour = {
            element: '#' + data.id + '-colourpicker',
            colour: data.colour
          };
          options.kelvin = {
            element: '#' + data.id + '-kelvinpicker',
            colour: data.colour
          };
        }
      });
      deferArr.push(_d)
      triggers[counter] = options;
      counter++;
    })
    $.when.apply($, deferArr).done(function() {
      console.log(triggers); //can see all nested objects
      console.log(triggers[0].colour); //returns null
      console.log('triggers:' + JSON.stringify(triggers)); // can only see parent object
    });
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when) is a reference to use array in $.when().

The foreach will push all defer in an array, and then use when method for that array which will wait for completion of all defers, and then executes done method.