# How to use $.when in node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I want to send a dynamic amount ajax requests at same time and want a callback to them all (i.e. the callback to the last one returning), but I am using node.js. I found a jquery version to solve it here
[Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when)
but how can I do this in node.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all takes an array of promises and returns a Promise of Array. The node-fetch module can be used to make HTTP requests asynchronously (AJAX only really refers to browser-executed requests.)

Bluebird is a nodejs Promise polyfill.

Something like

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch'),
    Promise = require('bluebird');

function fetchUrls(URLs) {
    return Promise.all(URLs.map(function (URL) {
        return fetch(URL).then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        });
    }));
}

fetchUrls(['url1','url2']).then(function (data) {
    // do stuff with the result data here
});
```

Comment: I dont understand where I can add my code that executes when the last callback returns.

Comment: Add a "then" callback to the promise, hangon

Comment: fyi Node 4+ has Promises

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS doesn't use AJAX, you have the HTTP API or [request](https://github.com/request/request). What you're trying to do can be solved with either Promises or the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

One way of solving the problem is this (untested):

```
   var async = require("async");
   var request = require("request");
   async.map(["https://target.com/a","https://target.com/b"], request, function (err, data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: How does this give me the callback to the last returning ajax?