# Error with pushing jquery ajax requests into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to push `ajax` requests into a `deferreds` `array`, but I constantly get the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

I've used this post as an example: [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when)

Am I overlooking something really obvious?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="../yajf.js"></script>
<script src="../yajf2.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var deferreds = [];
    $('script[src]').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        deferreds.push(
            $.get(src,function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }); // error gets thrown on this line
        );
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: }); // error gets thrown on this line to }) // error gets thrown on this line
remove ";"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added a `;` inside the (one-element) argument list for `deferreds.push()`. Remove the semicolon on that line.

```
    deferreds.push(
        $.get(src,function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }) // remove the semicolon from this line
    );
```

http://jslint.com