# How to chain methods in order to get results only at the end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a simple service method that gather several `.get()` and I'm having some troubles on the "printing" part as by that time I only have one part of the result.

what I'm doing is:

```
var service = function() {
  var players = []; // will hold 100 objects

  var getMembers = function(id) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var p = data[i];
        // get more info for this member
        getMemberDetails(p.member_id);
        // put the current data into the players
        players.push(p);
      }
    });

    calculateAndPrint();
  };

  var getMemberDetails = function(id) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      var result = $.grep(players, function(e){ return e.member_id == id; });
      if (result.length == 0) { /* not found */ } 
      else if (result.length == 1) {
        // push new data to player object
        result[0].details = data;
      }
    });
  };

  var calculateAndPrint = function() {
    for(i=0; i<players.length; i++) {
      var p = players[i];
      console.log(p);
    }
  };
})();
```

and this does not work, as when I reach `calculateAndPrint`, the `details` is not even designed yet...

so I tried `$.Deferred()` and the only issue I'm having is that if I defer `getMemberDetails` method, that call includes already a deffer call (the `.get()`) and I'm back to the same issue ...

what is the best option to only run `calculateAndPrint` after all 100 calls were made?

It seems easy enough but I'm just blank :/

Comment: you could increment a counter and when it reach 100, execute that function inside `getMemberDetails` callback

Comment: Are you sure you want to make 100+1 http requests for this data? Can't you batch all the 100 requests to get details into one call?

Comment: where you are using id and how to are invoking `getMembers()`?

Comment: @sethflowers no, ServiceAPI does not allow batching, I really need to call 100 times :/ - @hacketo trying to do things right learning the `defer` thingy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty easy if you use promises:

```
var service = function() {
  var getMembers = function(id) {
      return Promise.when($.get("some service url"))
          .then(function (data) {
              return Promise.all(data.map(getMemberDetails));
          });
  };

  var getMemberDetails = function(player) {
      return Promise.when($.get("some service Url?id=" + player.member_id));
  };

  var calculateAndPrint = function(players) {
      players.forEach(function (player) {
          console.log(player);
      });
  };

  return {
      getMembers: getMembers,
      calculateAndPrint: calculateAndPrint
  };
})();

service.getMembers().then(function (players) {
    service.calculateAndPrint(players);
});
```

Comment: darn... why was I looking to `$.Deferred()` instead? and good idea to put the chain outside, I was trying just to call `service.getMembers()` and get all at once :)

Answer (score -1):

you could just create a deferred object `$.deferred` for every ajax call your making & then wait (`$.when`) for all those deferred jobs to complete before you run the `calculateAndPrint()` method.

---

**How It Works:**

- Create a deferred object for every ajax call `$.deferred` & return the promise object `.promise()`.
- depending on whether ajax call is successful or not , either resolve with response data `.resolve(responseData)` or reject with error data `.reject(errorData)`.
- Monitor all the ajax calls by there promise objects returned from step1 and on completion , call the `calculateAndPrint()` method.
- For arbitrary ajax calls most of the above logic remains same,except that those are called in for loop and each of those deferred calls are pushed into a `deferredCalls` array.

*Note:I would suggest to show some loader/spinner image when your making ajax calls, since you would not get the response immediately & keeping user informed about the background operation is always good User experience sign.*

**JS CODE:**

```
/* utils */
var $ul = $('ul');

function msg(text) {
  $ul.append('<li>' + text + '</li>'); 
}

/* functions */
function asyncThing1() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    msg('asyncThing1 seems to be done...');
    dfd.resolve('banana');
 }, 1000);
 return dfd.promise();
}

function asyncThing2() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
    msg('asyncThing2 seems to be done...');
    dfd.resolve('apple');
  }, 500);
  return dfd.promise();
}

function asyncThing3() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    msg('asyncThing3 seems to be done...');
    dfd.resolve('orange');
  }, 1500);
  return dfd.promise();
}

/* do it */
$.when(asyncThing1(), asyncThing2(), asyncThing3()).done(function(res1, res2, res3) {
  msg('all done!');
  msg(res1 + ', ' + res2 + ', ' + res3);
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/8pR7n/382/)

---

**Arbitrary Deferred calls [Original SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16208232/1677272) :**

```
//Push all arbitrary ajax calls to deferred array
var deferreds = [];
function getSomeDeferredStuff() {
   var i = 1;
   for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      var count = i;
      deferreds.push(
        $.post('/echo/html/', {
          html: "<p>Task #" + count + " complete.",
          delay: count
        }).success(function(data) {
           $("div").append(data);
      }));
   }
}


// define a extension method for $.when for creating/managing deferred
// objects for every ajax call
if (jQuery.when.all===undefined) {
   jQuery.when.all = function(deferreds) {
      var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();
      $.when.apply(jQuery, deferreds).then(
          function() {
             var deferredObjs= function (arguments) { return deferreds.length > 1 ? $.makeArray(arguments) : [arguments]; }
             deferred.resolve(deferredObjs);
          },
          function() {
             deferred.fail(deferredObjs);
          });

      return deferred;
   }
}

//passing the deferred calls array to $.when
$.when.all(deferreds).then(function(objects) {
    //process when all deferred objects compelted
    console.log("Resolved/rejected objects:", objects);
});
```

[Working example for arbitrary ajax calls @JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNGcm/21/)

Comment: OP's question is about waiting on an arbitrary (i.e. not pre-determined) number of asynchronous operations after performing another asynchronous operation. Your answer shows how to wait on a specific number of parallel operations, so it does not answer OP's question.

Comment: well this was just syntax to make deferred calls and get notified when all are done.In order to make arbitrary deferred calls, one must just create a deferred array in a loop and then pass that deferred array to `$.when.apply`, so nothing much changes in the above solution when making arbitrary deferred calls.anyway for better understanding i`ll edit the answer.