# Loop through an array of urls and pass them to get_json, return the new array of datas

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach, getjson

I can't figure how to loop through an array of urls and pass them to `getJSON`, to finally return the new array of datas.

```
var data_num=[];
$.each(arr_urls, function( index, value ) {          
    $.getJSON(arr_urls[index], function (data) {});
    data_num.push(data);
});
alert(data_num);
```

Comment: You have to `push` the `data` *inside* of the callback.

Comment: I did it too originally but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes it works. Another problem of your code is that you `alert` the array *before* the callback is executed. So `data_num` is always empty when you run it.

Comment: If order of response doesn't matter, use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when  But you have firstly to understand how async call works

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done . There are a billion questions about jQuery, Ajax and async. Please use the search.

Comment: My bad for not allowing the response to arrive at alert time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data_num=[];
$.each(arr_urls, function( index, value ) {

  $.getJSON(arr_urls[index], function (data) {
      data_num.push(data);
      alert(data_num);
  });
});
```

Put your pusher and alert in the callback like this.

Comment: While this isn't incorrect, it leaves unclear how the op should access the final array.

Comment: by keys   'data_num.key' like it's user data then 'data_num.name'      and the other way is by index data_num[i]

Comment: Thank you Felix for leading me to jQuery .when, could it be a good way to retrieve it in this situation?

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you just do:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(arr_urls);
```