# Wait for asynchronous GETs to complete in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, design-patterns, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

I'm fully aware that `async: false` is [deprecated with XMLHttpRequest](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method), but the following code meets my immediate need to GET all pages before a subsequent task iterates over them.

```
for (i=0; i <= last_page; i++) {
      $.ajax({
          url : '/static/experiments/zoning_out_task/text/' + i + '.html',
          cache: false,
          async: false,
          success : function(result) {
              pages.push(result);
          }
      });
}
```

Is there a pattern that achieves the same thing using `async: true`?

Comment: So you use promises and call after all the requests are complete http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: You have to use [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) to achieve such behaviour.

Comment: Even You can change your code to reduce the number of ajax calls, try sending all the parameters at once instead of looping in the data and sending ajax calls.

Comment: You can refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when) as well

Answer (score 0):

in es6 you can use promisy.all if you need them all before continue to the next task

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

if you need to finish each task serially you can use async.waterfall

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

you also can achieve this by promises

```
var p1 = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('Success!');
  // or
  // reject ("Error!");
} );
    var p2 = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'foo');
  // or
  // reject ("Error!");
} );
p1.then( value => {
  console.log(value); // Success!
    // here you can call the second promise and so on 
    p2.then(value=>{
       console.log("second promise done",value)
    })
}, reason => {
  console.log(reason); // Error!
} );
```