# How force to run code on "Change" event after on "Focus" event is completly executed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jQuery script I need for comboboxes :

1. On `focus` event, run code in order to get all values before the user changes the value inside this `<select>`.
2. On `change` event, run code depending a json object built during `focus` event

**script**

```
var previousDataObject = [];

$('body').on('focus', "select.my-combobox", function () {
     comboboxChangeInit(); // it fills previousDataObject up;  
}).on( "change", "select.my-combobox", function(){ 
     //here code using previousDataObject 
});
```

The basic jQuery behaviour will run `focus` and `change` on user actions.

In my case, I need to wait `comboboxChangeInit()` fills previousDataObject up completly to run the code on `change` event.

How can I create a kind of listener to do this ?

Comment: Have `comboChangeInit()` return a promise.  Store that promise in a variable outside of the handler.  And the in the change event handler, attach a `then()` to that promise.

Comment: I´m trying to understand what you´re saying. Can you give me a generic piece of code to be clearer for me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `trigger` instead, so

```
$('body').on('focus', "select.my-combobox", function () {
     comboboxChangeInit(); // it fills previousDataObject up;
     $(this).trigger('change')
}).on( "change", "select.my-combobox", function(){ 
     //here code using previousDataObject 
});
```

`trigger` will fire the event passed as argument, please check the [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: I tried your example. With your code, the trigger run "change" event even if the user has just opened the combobox but did not select another value yet. If I display a spinner inside "Change" event, the spinner appears after "focus" without the user changed the value.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on deferred object thanks [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711173/how-to-use-jquery-promise-on-multiple-change-events).

**jQuery**

```
var previousDataObject = [];

var previousDataDeferred;

$('body').on('focus', "select.my-combobox", function () {
     comboboxChangeInit(); // it fills previousDataObject up.  
}).on( "change", "select.my-combobox", function(){ 
   var myObject = $(this); 
   $.when( previousDataDeferred ).done(function(){ 
         //Display spinner for example
         //here code using myObject and previousDataObject.
         //Remove spinner and reset previousDataObject  
   });
});

function comboboxChangeInit(){
   previousDataDeferred = $.Deferred();
   //Code to fill previousDataObject up.
   previousDataDeferred.resolve();
});
```