# What is the correct way to use jQuery When function to wait of some functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

I have a jquery method:

```js
$.when(
  function() {
    console.log("1st Func!");
  },
  function() {
    console.log("2nd Func!");
  }
).done(function() {
  console.log("Done Func!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I expect the first two method call and finished and at the end the done method run. I expect in console:

```
1st Func!
2nd Func!
Done Func!
```

But only the done method called and the console is like: `Done Func!`

Where is the problem?

**UPDATE:**

I get from the comments the function inside the **When** should be a promise. 
In actual sample I have:

```
var getAndSetFromAPI = function(keyName, callback){
    if (localStorage.getItem(keyName) === null){
        $.AjaxCall(.., .., callback(data));
    }
    else{
      if(callback){ callback(localStorage.getItem(keyName))}
    }
};
```

And I have a list of objects:

```
mylist.each(function (index, element){
      getAndSetFromAPI(element, function(date){fillData(element, data);}
});
```

So What is your suggestion to wait to complete each element and then go to process another one?

Comment: you're passing in functions, but `when` doesn't call them for you

Comment: The arguments to `$.when()` are supposed to be promises, not functions.

Comment: Your `getAndSetFromAPI` should not take a callback. It should return a promise. Always.

Comment: See [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1048572) once you got `mylist.map(getAndSetFromAPI)` to produce an array of promises

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:async-await], can you use ES8 features and real promises?