# Bitcoin - JavaScript - Calculating values using numeric results from separate functions and display without user interaction

Tags: javascript, api

JavaScript - Calculating values using numeric results from separate functions and display without user interaction.

I’m looking to calculate the percentage difference between returned API values (extracted from a single target API, but different ‘GET’ URL’s) and display the percentage differential.

I’m using separate functions to extract each value as the ‘GET’ URL is time stamped to perform searches for specific results.

Ive included only 2 functions, but would like to calculate the difference between more as required.

I’ve only included the Javascript, if there is a typo in the code, then it is only a typo, the functions display the relevant data, it is calculating the percentage difference between “BTC_Result_Now” (from the 1st function) and BTC_Result_1_Week (from the 2nd function) that proving not so straight forward:

```js
    
var BTC_XHR_Now = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    function getBTC_Price_Now() {
        var url = BTC_API_PriceNow;
        BTC_XHR_Now.open('GET', url, true,);
        BTC_XHR_Now.onload = function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(BTC_XHR_Now.responseText);
            var BTC_Result_Now = response.BTC.USD;
            document.getElementById("BTC-Price-Now").innerHTML = BTC_Result_Now; // $17077.13
        }
        BTC_XHR_Now.send();
    }
getBTC_Price_Now();    

    
  
var BTC_XHR_1_Week = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    function getBTC_Price_1_Week() {
        var url = BTC_API_Price1Week;
        BTC_XHR_1_Week.open('GET', url, true,);
        BTC_XHR_1_Week.onload = function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(BTC_XHR_1_Week.responseText);
            var BTC_Result_1_Week = response.BTC.USD;
            document.getElementById("BTC-Price-1-Week").innerHTML = BTC_Result_1_Week; // $13749.57
        }
        BTC_XHR_1_Week.send();
    }
getBTC_Price_1_Week();
```

Comment: This sounds like you need help with the maths, rather than the coding itself? To determine percentage difference, `<new> / <old> * 100`. E.g. `23000 / 20000 * 100 = 115%`, `17000 / 20000 *  100 = 85%`

Comment: I don't disagree Fubar, thanks for getting back, but how do you extract the new/old values from the functions to compute the desired % calculation?

Comment: Oh, I see. You might find this useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284209/how-to-use-multiple-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-values and this - https://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-difference.html