# jQuery multiple AJAX synchronous requests & dynamically added html and events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronous

I have the following javascript

```
// JavaScript Document
$("[name=students]").each(function(){

        var student_id  = $(this).attr("data-student_id");

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ajax_call = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/load.php",
            dataType: "html",
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            data:   { 
                        student_id: student_id
                    },

            success: function( response ) 
            {   
                // dynamically add radio buttons
                // html response is radio buttons with NAME of as_xxxx inside of parent div[name=students] element already in the DOM
                $("[name=students][data-student_id='"+student_id+"']").fadeIn( "slow").html(response).show();

            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                // show error message
            },
        });
        //END AJAX/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }).promise().done( function(){ 

        save_data();
    });
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  SAVE
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function save_data()
{

    //$(document).on('click','[name=student][name^=as_]',function(event) // WORKS IF ajax ASYNC = TRUE

    $("[name=student][name^=as_]").on("click",function(event)  // DOES NOT WORK IF ajax ASYNC = TRUE.   Works if ASYNC = FALSE
    {
        // SAVE RADIO BUTTON DATA ON CLICK
    });
}
</javascript>
```

The code works fine if async is FALSE.  But if asnyc is TRUE then I can't click any of the dynamically added radio buttons.

I am assuming that the promise().done code is firing BEFORE all the ajax synchronous requests are completed.

Is there a way to ensure a loops of synchronous ajax requests are completed??  OR why is the code not working?

Comment: Could be better just sending an array of students e.g: `[{"student_id": 1},{"student_id": 2}, {"student_id": 3}, {"student_id": 4}]` with a simple `$.ajax()` to the server.

Comment: Yeah sending an array of students is probably the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

So to make multiple ajax requests, that have asynchronous nature of course, since we are dealing with `http` requests, you should consider a `Promise.all` wrapped with some logic in the `promiseAll` api.
This example shows you how to make several async http calls and collect results, so you have something like

```
promiseAll(items, callback)
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
```

where you will get in the `then` all the results from the http calls, while the `callback` will actually do the async job (it maybe every kind of async process actually).

```js
// Simple XMLHttpRequest
// based on https://davidwalsh.name/xmlhttprequest
SimpleRequest = {
  call: function(what, response) {
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e) {}
      }
    }
    // state changes
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState === 4) { // done
        if (request.status === 200) { // complete 
          response(request.responseText)
        } else response();
      }
    }
    request.open('GET', what, true);
    request.send(null);
  }
}
//PromiseAll
// @author loretoparisi at gmail dot com
var promiseAll = function(items, block) {
  var promises = [];
  items.forEach(function(item, index) {
    promises.push(function(item, i) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return block.apply(this, [item, index, resolve, reject]);
      });
    }(item, index))
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
} //promiseAll

promiseAll([...new Array(3)], (item, index, resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Making request [" + index + "]")
    SimpleRequest.call('https://icanhazip.com/', function(result) {
      if (result) {
        console.log("Response[" + index + "] " + result);
        resolve(result);
      } else {
        reject(new Error("call error"));
      }
    })
  })
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works...solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627301/1459802
Updated code:

```
    // JavaScript Document
    $("[name=areas]").each(function(){

            var student_id  = $(this).attr("data-student_id");
            var deferreds = [];
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            deferreds.push( $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/load.php",
                dataType: "html",
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function(){
                },
                data:   { 
                            //some data
                        },

                success: function( response ) 
                {   
                    // dynamically add radio buttons
                    // html response is radio buttons with NAME of as_xxxx inside of #container (parent element)
                    $("[name=areas][data-student_id='"+student_id+"']").fadeIn( "slow").html(response).show();

                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    // show error message
                }
            }) //END AJAX/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            );

        }); // .each


         $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
              console.log("*************** DONE *****************");
             save_data();
            });    
    });
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    //  SAVE
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function save_data()
    {

        //$(document).on('click','#container [name^=as_]',function(event) // WORKS IF ajax ASYNC = TRUE

        $("[name=areas][name^=as_]").on("click",function(event)  // DOES NOT WORK IF ajax ASYNC = TRUE.   Works if ASYNC = FALSE
        {
            // SAVE RADIO BUTTON DATA ON CLICK
        });
    }
```