# Jquery $.when not waiting for promises to resolve, reject

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a dynamic array of API calls that need to go out.  However, jQuery's $.when does not appear to be waiting for promises to resolve or be rejected, or I'm not understanding how to use promises correctly.

**Code**

```
function addEntry(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    _customAPIClass_.post('some/url/path', data)
      .done(function(){
        console.log('resolving');
        resolve(1000)
      })
      .catch(function(){
        console.log('rejecting');
        reject(2000);
      })
  });
}

let deferreds = [];

$.each(form.find(el), function(i, element) {
  let data = {
    id: $(element).find('.id').val(),
    name: $(element).find('.name').val()
  }
  deferreds.push(addEntry(data));
}

if (deferreds.length) {
  $.when.apply(deferreds).then(function(data){
    console.log('All done', data)
  }, function(err){
    console.log('error', err);
  });
}
```

**Console output**
*Two api calls rejecting promise after .then() executes*
[image: console output]

So, what I don't understand, and what other questions here on Stack Overflow or on the jQuery docs aren't helping me solve, is why is the `.then()` acting like everything is OK before the API calls have completed and resolved or rejected their promises? How do I handle resolves or rejects after all API calls have been made, or am I misunderstand the purpose of the `.when()` and promises?

Comment: your `.apply` appears to be missing something quite important. (it takes two arguments)

Comment: any particular reason you're using .apply and not just calling .when() directly? See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ for usage examples. Also note that it still won't wait for everything to finish necessary - as soon as any of the promises is rejected, it'll fire the callback.

Comment: @ADyson because $.when doesn't accept an array.

Comment: Ah ok sorry I missed that.

Comment: In that case: Possible duplicate of [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when)

Comment: Ok, so that worked, for the most part.  Thanks.  Now I just need to figure how to properly handle the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

$.when.apply(deferreds)

to:

$.when.apply($, deferreds)

As described here: https://medium.com/sungthecoder/making-multiple-ajax-calls-and-deciphering-when-apply-array-b35d1b4b1f50 and as mentioned in Kevin B's comment:

"When we call $.when() function, ‘this’ keyword inside the function is implicitly bind to jQuery object. But when we call $.when.apply(), we have to explicitly bind ‘this’ keyword to something. And we know that the binding has to be with jQuery object, so we pass jQuery object, a.k.a., $ as the first argument."

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Handling promises keeps tripping me up, hard to wrap my head around for some reason.