# Why is my jQuery promise resolving immediately?

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

Using jQuery promises, I'm trying to:

1. Call an API for all possible values (of an animal)
2. Call an API method for each animal (animal sound)
3. Notify when each animal sound comes back - let's say it takes a while to work out
4. Notify when all animal sounds have been returned

I'm putting all the animal sound functions into an array then calling `$.when()`. I expect this to resolve when all animal sounds have returned, but I'm finding that it resolves immediately. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
function () {
  $('#txtNotification').text('Started ....');

  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/animals/all"
  }).done(function(data) {
    var animalFunctions = [];

    for (var animalType of data) {
      var animalFunction = $.ajax({
        url: "/api/animal/sound/" + animalType
      }).done(function(data) {
        $('#txtNotification').text(data);
      });

      animalFunctions.push(animalFunction);
    }

    $.when(animalFunctions).then(function() {
      $('#txtNotification').text('Done.');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) is one of the few jQuery functions which [cannot accept an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1813169)

Comment: Adding on to @MTCoster's comment, try changing `$.when(animalFunctions)` to `$.when(...animalFunctions)`. The spread operator (`...`) can turn your array into a list of arguments.

Comment: That’s what I’d recommend. The pre-ES6 solution would have been `$.when.apply($, animalFunctions)`

Comment: @MTCoster. Brilliant. That's worked. I would have never have got that. If you write it as an answer I will upvote and accept. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) is one of the few jQuery functions which [cannot accept an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1813169) - you’ll need to call it with each promise as a separate argument:

**The ES6 way:**

```
$.when(...animalFunctions).then(() => {
  $('#txtNotification').text('Done.');
});
```

**The stone age way:**

```
$.when.apply($, animalFunctions).then(function () {
  $('#txtNotification').text('Done.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`Deferred.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) allows you to "notify" the progress of the individual items.

```js
var $def = jQuery.Deferred();

$.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
})
.done(function getUsersAsync(users) {
  for (var user of users) {
    $def.notify(`Fetching comments of ${user.username}, ID: ${user.id}`);
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
      data: JSON.stringify({ id: user.id })
    })
    .done(function (arg) {
      // Do stuff with the comments here
    });
  }
  
  $def.resolve(users.length);
})
.fail(function () {
  $def.reject('ERR: Failed retrieving comments');
});


$def
  .progress(function (message) {
    console.log(message);
  })
  .done(function (count) {
    console.log('ALL DONE. Total user: ' + count);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Add `return: false` to the anon function passed to .done(). See if that helps.

```
function () {
        $('#txtNotification').text('Started ....');

        $.ajax({
                url: "/api/animals/all"
            })  
            .done(function( data ) {

                var animalFunctions = [];

                for (var animalType of data) {

                    var animalFunction = $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/animal/sound/" + animalType
                        })
                        .done(function(data) {
                            $('#txtNotification').text(data);
                            return false;
                        }
                    );

                    animalFunctions.push(animalFunction);
                }

                $.when(animalFunctions).then(function() {
                    $('#txtNotification').text('Done.');
                });
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That hasn't work though. Cheers