# How to dynamically add deferred objects to $.when() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, promise, deferred

Here is an example of a standard usage of `$.when()` in jQuery:

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();
var d3 = $.Deferred();

$.when(d1, d2, d3).done(function (v1, v2, v3 ) {
});
```

Is it possible to pass 1 or more deferred variables on the fly?  Say I suddenly have 5 deferred to check for their resolve, how would I dynamically insert those 5 to the `$.when()` without hard-coding `$.when(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5)....`?

Comment: Use an array to pass to `$.when`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when

Comment: Also can use Promise.all() with array of the deferreds  instead of `$.when` if using jQuery 3+

Comment: Thank you  charlietfl.  The .apply() works.  I'll look into that Promise.all() to see what that is.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

As per charlietfl, the $.when.apply($, promisesArray) did the trick.