# Manage timeout ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to manage an ajax call with timeout with `.when` and `.then`.

I have a script like this:

```
$.when(
        $.ajax({   
            url: url_ajax, 
            type: "GET", 
            async: true,
            data: window.location.search, 
            dataType: "json", 
            timeout: 30000,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('ok');
            },
            error: function(data) {

            }
        }),
        $.ajax({   
            url: url_ajax, 
            type: "GET", 
            async: true,
            data: window.location.search, 
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('ok');
            },
            timeout: 30000,
            error: function(data) {

            }
        })
     ).then(function() {
          alert('end');
     });
```

If an ajax request go in timeout the callback `.then` isn't called and I can't see the last alert.
So if my ajax request go in timeout I can't exit enter into `then` function.

I have also tried to add this after each ajax request:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            if(textStatus == 'timeout')
            {     
                alert('Failed from timeout'); 
            }
         })
```

But again doesn't enter into `then` function

How can I manage timeout?
Thanks

Comment: See the API: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/. Have you tried `.then(successCallbackFunction, failCallbackFunction)`?

Comment: can you please provide an example with my code to understand well what'is the good way? @mccannf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `.then(successCallbackFunction, failCallbackFunction)` like so:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({   
        url: url_ajax, 
        type: "GET", 
        async: true,
        data: window.location.search, 
        dataType: "json", 
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('ok');
        },
        error: function(data) {

        }
    }),
    $.ajax({   
        url: url_ajax, 
        type: "GET", 
        async: true,
        data: window.location.search, 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('ok');
        },
        timeout: 30000,
        error: function(data) {

        }
    })
 ).then( // success
         function() {
           alert('Success!');
         },
         // failure
         function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            if(textStatus == 'timeout')
            {     
                alert('Failed from timeout'); 
            } else {
                alert('Failed from: '+textStatus);
            }
         }
 );
```

Comment: There is a little problem, if the first is aborted go immediately to failure function before the second end. I would like to have a failure function run when all request finished if there is an error. is possible?

Comment: You need something custom for that. See the second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518181/jquery-deferreds-when-and-the-fail-callback-arguments