# Ajax - Handle 404 error in jquery $.when

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have the following code:

```
function ajax1(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}

function ajax2(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}

function ajax3(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}

function ajax4(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}
```

I then run the Ajax calls and access the data returned by each one using `$.when`:

```
$.when(ajax1(url), ajax2(url), ajax3(url), ajax4(url)).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){

});
```

Now, let's say one of the Ajax calls, `ajax2`, will return a 404 error.

How can prevent the script from executing and still return something (like false, to be accessed using the `a2` variable) even when a 404 error is returned?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518181/jquery-deferreds-when-and-the-fail-callback-arguments

Comment: @Barmar had a look at that, still not sure how I would go about implementing

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Is it 3+ ?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery 3 Deferreds are [Promises A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) compliant. That means you can add a `catch()` to the request promise

Whenever you *return* from a `catch()` it resolves the promise and whatever is returned will be passed to the next `then()` in the chain

```js
function ajax1(url) {
  return $.ajax({
      url: url
    })
    .then(data => data)
    .catch(resolveFailure);
}

function resolveFailure(jqXhr) { 
  // return whatever you want here. I added the status in case that is of interest
  // could return `false` or string or whatever
  // can also log any issues back to server if needed
  return {
    error: true,
    status: jqXhr.status,
    statusText: jqXhr.statusText
  };
}

var req = ajax1('https://api.myjson.com/bins/l9ywp'),
    req2 = ajax1('https://httpbin.org/FAIL'),
    req3 = ajax1('https://api.myjson.com/bins/l9ywp');

// could also replace `$.when with `Promise.all()`
$.when(req, req2, req3).then(function(r1, r2, r3) {
  // validate the arguments based on whatever you return in the catch()
  console.log('r1', r1);
  console.log('r2', r2);// object returned from catch()
  console.log('r3', r3);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! This is what I want. One question, is the `.then(data => data)` required in `ajax1()`? The syntax doesn't seem right.

Comment: It's arrow function syntax equivalent to `then(function(data){ return data})`. It's up to you what you want to see in `$.when`. If you use `Promise.all()` instead of `$.when` only the data will show up without that step

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `done()` from `$.when()`, try `then()` like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/L83ny70k/

In the JSFiddle check your console to see the response from the failed request!

JQuery's `when().then()` can take 2 functions, the first will trigger if all requests resolve, similar to how `done()` works, the second will trigger if any of the requests fails and will pass the response of that failed request through to your function so you can do what you will with it!

Hope that helps :)

**More info**

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

EDIT: This solution will stop you from accessing the responses for all other successful requests. Thanks for pointing that out @charlietfl!

Comment: Thanks for this. However, the onSuccess console.log doesn't fire?

Comment: @SergiuTripon it won't for same reason your original code won't

Comment: @charlietfl, not sure what you mean... but it definitely works if you change url2 to the same thing as url1 so it actually doesn't fail.

Comment: But OP wants not to have one request failure prevent access to success of the others. Read the question closer. In other words...regardless of status of the requests your `onError` should never fire

Comment: Agree the wording is a bit clumsy but read on about accessing `a2` regardless if 404 or not and be able to access the good requests also

Comment: Ah I get what you mean now, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

The last bit on the [$.when() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) has something that might help you:

> Execute the function myFunc when both ajax requests are successful, or
>   myFailure if either one has an error.

Example:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

Now, if you want to know the failure for individual calls, you can also get individual status codes for each call, so that a call like:

```
function ajax2(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}
```

could get converted to something like:

```
function ajax2(url) {
    var isGoodResponse = $.ajax(url).always(function(xhr){
         console.log(xhr);
         // do whatever checks you want here
         return xhr.statusCode === '404';
    });
    // returns true/false
    return isGoodResponse;
}
```

For example:

```js
$.ajax("http://false-url.duh")
    .always(function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't see how this answers OP question. Op wants it so regardless of status `myFunc` fires always and myFailure never fires