# Done method is not working when one of multiple Ajax Requests fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred, .when

I am out after making multiple Ajax calls in a row and do something else when all of the requests are over.

The first round works fine because all of the requests return **success 200**. However, the second round fails to enter the done() method here due to the fact that some Ajax calls fail to respond ( they give 404 ). Let's say that the call ajaxCall(url5) fails by entering its own error function.

But still, I want to call a method inside the done() method so that I can make use of the responses that I get from the successful calls.

Any ideas why done() does not work when one of the calls fails OR how to make sure that I can be at the right spot when all of the calls are made regardless of their status is success or error?

```
function ajaxCall(endpoint){        
  return $.ajax({
    url: endpoint, 
    cache: false,
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {          
      console.log("404");    
    },
    success: function(response) {
      result = $(response).find("#boxContent");       
      $(".boxContainer").append(result[0].innerHTML);     
    }
  });   
}

$.when(ajaxCall(url1),
       ajaxCall(url2),
       ajaxCall(url3),
       ajaxCall(url4),
       ajaxCall(url5)).then(function(){
  console.log("All requests issued.");
}, function() {      
  console.log("One of the sources is not available*****************"); 
  hasAnyFailed = true;
}).done(function( a1, a2, a3, a4, a5){      
  // When all calls return
  console.log("DONE*********);   
  doSomethingElse();
});
```

PS : I found this SO solution, but not quite sure if we have an update solution like a built-in JS method.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881733/2790804

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Solution will be cleaner if using v 3+

Comment: @charlietfl It is v1.7.1 , I am doing the implementation on HubSpot 
https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-general/how-do-i-select-which-version-of-jquery-is-included-across-my-pages

Comment: Can use `.always()` but won't have data passed to it. Or could write `ajaxCall()` to return a `jQuery.Deferred()` promise you create and have it resolve in both `success` and `error`

Comment: Can you give an example of such multiple calls ?